# Chrome on Linux does not allow to download .deb file

Tags: linux, google-chrome, security, download

I rather know what am I doing if I want to download .deb file. The problem is how does it work on Chrome. After I click download link, nothing happens. No any message shown, no warning, just no reaction.

Is there any way to again take control and decide what I want to download?

Comment: use a good browser?

Comment: Well, my question is related to Chrome

Comment: Sorry, I meant test with a good browser - see if it's a chrome *feature*

Comment: This sounds like the redirection problem inherent on many chrome based browser. Try grabbing the file with curl or wget and observe if there is a redirect, if so, then complain to google and get them to fix it. They have known about this problem for years and seem to have no interest in doing anything about it.

Comment: No redirections, example - direct link: http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/f/firefox-esr/firefox-esr_115.6.0esr-1~deb12u1_amd64.deb but if you click no site: https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/amd64/firefox-esr/download there's no any reaction. Need to paste destination url to address bar. The same effetct when try to clik here (link I pasted)

Comment: `see if it's a chrome feature ` - yes, it's only Chrome's "feature". I am ablo to download from the same url on Firefox (or wget/curl in terminal) without any problems

Comment: Does it happen in Chrome Incognito mode?

Comment: Yes. Can anybody click above link from my comment, can you reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is because it is run over http rather than https. Here with Vivaldi, it fails on the former without error, yet works on the latter.

When I try it in the latest google chrome, it says the download is blocked due to insecure download.

It again works with an https connection.

Next time, give an example in your question, rather than later in the comments.